# Getting "Unable to serialize <iondatetime> as string" when converting to C# datetime in Ionic 4

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, typescript, ionic4

I am struggling to serialize dates in ionic.

My Model is:

```
export class Learner {
    name: string;
    phone: number;
    email:string;
    address: string;
    photo: string;
    dob: any;
    id:number;
    uid:string;
}
```

Html

```
  <ion-label>DOB</ion-label>
      <ion-datetime displayFormat="DD MMM, YYYY"  formControlName="dob" placeholder="Date of birth"></ion-datetime>
    </ion-item>
```

Ts:

```
     var learner:Learner=
      {
        name: this.learnerOnboardForm.value.name,
        phone: parseInt(this.learnerOnboardForm.value.phone),
        email: this.learnerOnboardForm.value.email,
        address: this.learnerOnboardForm.value.address,
/* trying to serialize this*/        
dob:moment(this.learnerOnboardForm.value.dob).format('MMMM Do YYYY,h:mm:ss a'),
        photo:this.learnerOnboardForm.value.photo,
        id:0,
        uid:this.fUserCred.user.uid
      };
```

I am trying to save the date and send it to a c# controller. I tried date, datetime, others finally figured out only way is string.

If I log the value from the formcontrol, it is an array:

[image: iondatetime value from control]

I tried to change the format with moment.js which says "invalid date".

I tried converting to date which also says "invalid date".

C# Controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Add ([FromBody]Learner l)
        {
          await this.learnerCommandLogic.Add(l);
          return Ok("learner added sucessfully");
        }

public class Learner : BaseBusinessEntity
    {
        public string Uid { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string  Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public double Phone { get; set; }

        [EmailAddress]
        [Required]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public string Address { get; set; }

        public string Photo { get; set; }

        public string Dob { get; set; }

    }
```

API.Learners log

```
http://localhost:8100/api/Learners
```

im getting bad request here as the date is not getting serialized

The main issue is the date is coming as a Json of 3 objects month,date,year.

```
i want to send it as a single string of datetime like '10/09/2016 ...'
```

Comment: could u plz show your posted data to controller?

Comment: addLearner(learner: Learner): Observable<Learner> {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json'
      })};
    console.log(Api.Learners);
    return this.http.post<Learner>(Api.Learners, learner, httpOptions);
  }The datatype at c# is string im parsing it to datetime

Comment: Ok, could u please show the data inside "console.log(Api.Learners)"?

Comment: also add your c# controller code in your question

Comment: Share the sample `json` you are receiving from the server.

Comment: guys please help updated with the comments